# Group-tab addon for firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

I'm probably just entering the wrong search terms, but I'm pretty sure the firefox addons site has an addon that enables tabs in tabs.

For instance, a master tab for all news sites, one for all games sites, one for all programming, etc...

It's much easier to manage that way.

Does anybody know what it's called and where I can find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just installed [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10254) on Firefox 3.5.2 (OS X). It's rather sweet! It gives you a hierarchical tab bar on the *side* of your browser window (which you can set to auto hide).

It doesn't look like it supports manual tab renaming so you'll have to use, say, *google.com* as your gmail/cal/reader/analytics/etc. holder.

Thanks for asking the question; wish I'd thought of looking for an add-on like this sooner.

Comment: You can't rename tabs, but you can use groups. Just go to `about:treestyletab-group?GroupName`

Answer (score 2):

[Tab Kit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5447) has some cool extras over Tree Style Tab, like coloring each group distinctly.  Give both a try (but not at the same time!).

Comment: nice but doesn't work with Firefox Quantum

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Firefox Add-ons site, searched for keyword "group" in the "Tabs" category, and got back a bunch of add-ons that should work for you:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=group&cat=1%2C93.  I'm not sure which one specifically you're after, but it should appear in that list somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has now been added natively in Firefox 5 and you can [find more information](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-are-tab-groups) on the support site. It's a bit preliminary and has some issues, but it's looking promising.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple Tab Groups](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-tab-groups/) might help, see screenshots:

[image]

[image]